# How to get MapControl from ContentPresenter DataTemplate in UWP C#?

Tags: c#, windows-10-universal, uwp-maps

I have a ContentPresenter and I have assigned a `DataTemplate` to its `ContentTemplate` attribute. Now I want to add a `MapIcon` in `MapControl` which is child of DataTemplate as shown below:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="EWDetailsContentTemplate" x:DataType="viewModels:Task">

        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel"
                  Background="White"
                  Margin="0,5,0,0">

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Maps:MapControl x:Name="LocationMapControl"  
                             MapServiceToken="key"
                             Grid.Row="0"
                             Height="250"/>
         //more controls
       </Grid>
```

How can I get MapControl using VisualTree concept of C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get MapControl using VisualTree concept of C#?

You can use [VisualTreeHelper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/br243038(v=win.10).aspx?appid=dev14idef1&l=en-us&k=k(windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper)%3bk(targetframeworkmoniker-.netcore,version%3dv5.0)%3bk(devlang-csharp)&rd=true) to get the `MapControl` using following codes:

```
//This function will get all the children Control of one Controls' Container
public List<Control> AllChildren(DependencyObject parent)
{
    var _List = new List<Control>();
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++)
    {
        var _Child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
        if (_Child is Control)
            _List.Add(_Child as Control);
        _List.AddRange(AllChildren(_Child));
    }
    return _List;
}

private MapControl GetMapControl()
{
    var controls = AllChildren(myContentPresenter);//"myContentPresenter" is your ContentPresenter's name.
    var mapControl = (MapControl)controls[0];
    return mapControl;
}
```